# How could we get the accountId which is associated to a community self-registration setting

Tags: apex, community

We can setup an associating account on a community.

I'd like to know How could we get the associated Account through Apex code?

Is there any field I could query from the SOQL or APEX class?

e.g:

SELECT ID, Name, SelfRegProfileId, `SelfRegAccountId` FROM Network WHERE ID= xxx

[image]

Comment: Do you want to define the account on this screen or you are looking a way on how will an account be identified when a User does a self registration?

Comment: I'm saying I've already defined here. But on the backend code I need to find a way this field is setup or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `NetworkSelfRegistration` object here. From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_networkselfregistration.htm):

> Represents the account that self-registering community members are associated with by default. Self-registering users in a community are required to be associated with an account, which the administrator must specify while setting up self-registration for the community.

So your query will be as:

```
SELECT AccountId FROM NetworkSelfRegistration WHERE NetworkId = 'id of the community'
```

Comment: And for the corresponding profile. We need to query from `SELECT ID, Name, SelfRegProfileId FROM Network` ? Not sure why Salesforce separate this information into 2 diffrent tables LOL

Comment: Everyday is a new day in Salesforce :). Glad that it worked out for you.